# Maximum and minimum of this complex periodic function

Tags: trigonometry, optimization, fourier-analysis

I came up with this function by using Fourier transform. My only problem is how to get the amplitude of this function. Im planning to get the difference between their maxima and minima.  I get its first derivative then equate it to zero then plug the value of $x$ to the original function but the value of $x$ is just one. I need to get two critical points at least. But I just got one.

This is the function:

$ f(t) = 9.364984
-\frac{5441 \cos(2π(8.141334)(t-2456349.714))}{200000}+\frac{1481 \cos(2π(16.282667)(t-2456349.714))}{250000} +\frac{17397 \sin(2π(8.141334)(t-2456349.714))}{125000} - \frac{10557 \sin(2π(16.282667)(t-2456349.714))}{500000} -\frac{1139 \cos(2π(24.424001)(t-2456349.714))}{200000}+\frac{29 \cos(2π(32.565334)(t-2456349.714))}{50000} + \frac{753 \sin(2π(24.424001)(t-2456349.714))}{250000} - \frac{\sin(2π(32.565334)(t-2456349.714))}{200000}  $

Comment: Given that the coefficients are numerical anyway, it seems reasonable to use a numerical routine to find the maximum and minimum of the function.

Comment: Since all the terms have the same shift (2456359.714), you can simplify by transforming away the shift.

Comment: If we let $\theta = 2\pi\cdot 8.141334\cdot(t - 2456349.714)$ we'll get an expression with constants of exact numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\theta = 2\pi\times8.141334\times(t-2456349.714)$ ignore the constant term 9.364984, the function to optimize then becomes

$$
g(\theta) = \frac{5441}{200000}\cos\theta + \frac{1481}{250000}\cos 2\theta + \frac{17397}{125000}\sin\theta - \frac{10557}{500000}\sin2\theta - \frac{1139}{200000}\cos 3\theta + \frac{29}{50000}\cos4\theta + \frac{753}{250000}\sin3\theta-\frac{1}{200000}\sin4\theta
$$

Thus the derivative is also some linear combination of sine and cosine of $\theta, 2\theta, 3\theta, 4\theta$. Using $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1\implies\sin\theta=\pm\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta}$ and the [multiple angle formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multiple-AngleFormulas.html) the trigonometric equation $g'(\theta)=0$ can then be reduced to an *octic* (degree-8) equation of $\cos\theta$, which for sure does not have any general closed form exact solution.

Therefore, the maximum and minimum can only be solved numerically. (The maximum is attained at $\theta = 2.038368167$ and minimum at $\theta = 4.507982189$, by the way.)

Note that the [root mean square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square) $\sqrt{\frac1T \int_0^T f(t)^2dt}$ can be computed quite easily instead of the amplitude.

Comment: what do you mean by using the $ \sin^2x+\cos^2x=1 $ ? I don't get it? I just derived what you've said and this was the result.

$ \frac{2259cos3\theta}{250000} +\frac{3417sin3\theta}{200000}+\frac{17397cos\theta}{125000}-\frac{cos4\theta}{50000}-\frac{29sin4\theta}{12500}-\frac{1481sin2\theta}{125000}-\frac{5441sin \theta}{200000}-\frac{10557cos2\theta}{250000} $

Comment: @Joem: Please check update. Anyway there is no closed-form exact solution for this, you must resort to numerical solution at some point.

Comment: Im sorry I didn't get the whole process. If you mind, could you list down the process step by step? I got the θ=2.038368167, but couldn't find how the minimum is attained. Thank you.

Comment: @Joem I just throw the whole expression into Mathematica :|.

Comment: never mind, i just found out new method which is almost exactly same as you've done.. thanks anyway